# DrawerLayout - controlar visibilidade

Tags: java, android

Quando o app é executado o primeiro drawer apresentado está correto ou seja; vem só com um item de opção visível. Essa opção ao ser selecionada ativa uma activity que está sendo executada normalmente mas ao término da sua execução as outras opções não ficam visiveis.

drawer_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_register" android:visible="true">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_register"
            android:title="@string/drawer_register"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_24dp" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/drawer_app"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_app" android:visible="false">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_app_login"
                android:title="@string/drawer_app_login"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_fingerprint_black_24dp" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_app_logout"
                android:title="@string/drawer_app_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Main Activity

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.main_navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.main_navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.getMenu().clear();
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_teste);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Listener

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    // ================================================================================== //
    //                                FUNCTION REGISTER ME                                //
    // ================================================================================== //

    if (id == R.id.nav_drawer_register) {
        Toast toast =
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        R.string.device_register_warning, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        userType = "0"; 
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterStatusListActivity.ACTION_REG_STATUS_DATA);
        intent.addCategory(RegisterStatusListActivity.CATEGORY_REG_STATUS_DATA);
        intent.putExtra(RegisterStatusListActivity.EXTRA_REG_TYPE, userType);
        startActivity(intent);
        setAllVisible(true);       // <===== ATIVA MUDANÇA DE VISIBILIDADE
        return true;
    } else
```

setAllVisible

```
public void setAllVisible(boolean visible){

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
        findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.getMenu().clear();
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_teste);
        toggleVisibility(navigationView.getMenu(), R.id.drawer_app, visible);
    }

    private void toggleVisibility(Menu menu, @IdRes int id, boolean visible){
        menu.findItem(id).setVisible(visible);
}
```

RESUMO

Ao término da activity que processou a primeira opção selecionada o drawer continua com as demais opções invisíveis. Isso tem solução?

Comment: O correto seria você criar em um só, e somente alterar visibilidade quando o usuário fizesse o acesso, se ele não fizer, as opções continuam invisíveis.

Answer (score 1):

Faça dois menus e infle eles de acordo com a necessidade, se está logado ou não.

Exemplo:

Crie esses dois menus no diretório de menus

menu_logado.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_login"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_login"
            android:title="Login" />
    </group>


</menu>
```

menu_deslogado.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_logout"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Ai no java, tu infla eles com um if, assim

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

```
if(islogin)
    {
        navigationView.getMenu().clear();
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_logado);
    } else
    {
        navigationView.getMenu().clear();
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_deslogado);
```

Comment: Leonardo bom dia.